# How to change option card's color upon pressed in Flutter Quiz App?

Tags: flutter

I have  a list of questions with their options along with the true false values as following:

```
List <Question> _questions = [
    Question(id: '10', title: 'What is 2+2?', options: {
      '5':false, '4':true, '3':false, '2':false
}),
    Question(id: '11', title: 'What is 3*2?', options: {
      '6':true, '5':false, '3':false, '10':false
    }),
];
```

I have an OptionCard which changes color to green or red with correct and false option selected respectively. But upon selection the card is only displaying false color despite true option chosen:

my code for this:

```
OptionCard(
                          option: _questions[index].options.keys.toList()[i],
                        color: isClicked
                            ? _questions[index].options.keys.toList()[i] == true
                        ? kCorrectAnswerColor : kFalseAnswerColor
                            : kPrimaryColor,
                        onTap: _changeColor,
                      ),
```

I already have this property in Questions class of which's type List is:

```
final Map <String, bool> options;
```

What might be the reason of this inconvenience?

Comment: A tip since you managed to solve it, use another attribute that saves correct answer index ( or the string value) so you don’t need to compare with list every time.

You could do something like :

`optionIndex== _questions[index].correctIndex? kCorrectAnswerColor: kFalseAnswerColor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code snippet, `_questions[index].options.keys.toList()[i]` retrieves an option string like `'5', '4', '3', '2', etc`. However, you're comparing it directly with the boolean value 'true', which is causing the unexpected behavior.

You need to extract the boolean value corresponding to the selected option from the options map and compare it to true to determine if the selected option is correct. Here's how you can update your OptionCard code:

```
OptionCard(
  option: _questions[index].options.keys.toList()[i],
  color: isClicked
      ? _questions[index].options[_questions[index].options.keys.toList()[i]] == true
          ? kCorrectAnswerColor
          : kFalseAnswerColor
      : kPrimaryColor,
  onTap: _changeColor,
),
```

In this code, `_questions[index].options[_questions[index].options.keys.toList()[i]]` retrieves the boolean value corresponding to the selected option, and then it's compared with true to determine whether the selected option is correct or not. The color will change to green (correct) or red (false) based on the comparison result.

This should ensure that the correct color is displayed based on whether the selected option is true or false.